# How can I prevent text from expanding outside of div?

Tags: html, css

When you click on the about tab on the home page of this site: http://suncoastlaw.com/, and shrink the browser size down, the text overflows outside of the div. I've searched around and have tried `clear:both`, `overflow: hidden`, and several other things but can't seem to get the div to fluidly expand to the proper height to contain content. How do I make the div expand to contain content?

Comment: what browser/version are you testing this with? It seems okay with Firefox 18  and IE8 here

Comment: @PraveenKumar It's `div#tabedarea.group`. Confirmed in Chrome 24, Firefox 18, and Safari 6 on OS X 10.8.2.

Comment: Show your relevant mark-up, and CSS, *here*. Don't try and force us to visit an external site to try and work out, or frankly *guess*, where the problem might be. The questions here should stand alone, and be usable even in the event that your site falls over (or when it's fixed), in order to be of use to later visitors. You have >100 rep, so you should *know* this by now.

Comment: I'm testing it in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Modifiy the stylesheet file by Remove "min-height" and "height" from "#tabedarea" selector.

Also, Remove height: 365px; from the below DIV (this value came from JavaScript plugin)

```
<div class="list-wrap group" style="height: 365px;">
```

you can attach the following event to the browser window re-sizing in order to reset the height of the element:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   $(".list-wrap").height("auto");
});
```

EDIT:

Or just comment the below line in "functions.js":

```
$allListWrap.height(curListHeight);
```

Comment: That inline css isnt showing up in my local html file. It must be getting injected by a javascript tabs plugin that I'm using